# How to test Jenkins shared library with Jenkins itself?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a repository with a groovy file `vars/basicPipeline.groovy` that contains a single function `call`. This repository is used as Jenkins' Shared Library.

Mentioned file looks something like this:

```
def call(Map config, Closure body) {
    node(config.nodeLabel) {
        body()
    }
}
```

This library is then used like this:

```
basicPipeline nodeLabel: 'node' {
  echo 'Hello, World!'
}
```

I would like to test changes into this library with Jenkins itself, by running some demo pipeline, showing that provided `basicPipeline` is working.

But I have hard times creating pipeline, that will use own version of library rather than **master** configured in Jenkins.

I've tried:

- `@Library("myrepo@${BRANCH_NAME}") _` but it doesn't work with variables.
- `library "my-shared-library@$BRANCH_NAME"` says `Only using first definition of library`, and uses **master**.
- Simple invocation of `basicPipeline.call` still invokes version of library loaded from **master**.

How can I make my pipeline use local version of file, or load version from the same branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
      library "your-library-name@${branch}"
```

this should work
if you disable global injection of library in jenkins configuration (load implicitly)
and if you dont have `@Library("myrepo@${BRANCH_NAME}") _` at the beginning of pipeline

Jenkinsfile full content

```
library "your-library-name@${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
basicPipeline nodeLabel: 'node' {
  echo 'Hello, World!'
}
```

library should be added to global libraries with

- allow default version to be overridden

Comment: Can this be done without changing "load implicitly" option?

Comment: i don't know any way to do it, this is problem of "implicitly" your library included everywhere as result you can not reuse the same name of pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Well,  You want to bind SpockFramework with JenkinsPipeline Unit to provide unit testing for the library.  I've done that twice now and it vastly improves development speed.

- unit tests executed by IDE and test job (Intellij community edition works nicelu)
- system test to handle the gap between mock / stub and reality
- [SpockFramework](https://spockframework.org/) - great interaction testing with full and partial mocking
- [JenkinsPiplineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) - you can redefine jenkins pipeline functions to work the "same" locally
- [example](https://github.com/macg33zr/pipelineUnit/tree/0dcd54f46e2733c141da0ce6fb5158f010fee645)

Your test classes inherit from both Spock and Pipeline unit - groovy lacks multiple inheritance so we use a bit of meta programming to delegate from the Spock test base to the pipeline unit test base.

```
package ...
import com.lesfurets.jenkins.unit.BasePipelineTest
import static com.lesfurets.jenkins.unit.MethodSignature.method
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.rules.TestName

class PipelineTestHelper extends BasePipelineTest {
@Rule TestName name
...}


class PipelineSpockTestBase extends Specification implements RegressionTest{
    /**
     * Delegate jenkins DSL to the helper class
     */
    @Delegate PipelineTestHelper pipelineTestHelper
    ...
```